# Running "bjam" on macOS

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, cufflinks

Good morning,
I'm having troubles to run `bjam` on my Mac (macOS Mojave version 10.14.6).
I have successfully downloaded Boost (v1.75.0) and also ran the the script bootstrap.sh as follows:

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

and then

```
./b2
```

However, I still cannot run `bjam`.

I have also looked up the web (StackOverflow, Manuals and other forums) and apparently I did everything with no warnings or errors (that puzzles me even more).

Comment: ***I still cannot run bjam*** Why can't you? What happens?

Comment: when i try to run it for Cufflink purposes, terminal simply gives me this: -bash: bjam: command not found

Comment: Then use your OS file explorer tool to look to see if this file exists and where it is on your filesystem.

Comment: I found it... thank you!